# Can you customise Layout.Navigation.Menu in CompositeC1?

Tags: c1-cms

Is there a way to customise the Layout.Navigation.Menu function in CompositeC1 or perhaps duplicate this function with one I can edit? I need to add unique IDs to the rendered elements  so I can create an image based menu rather than text only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function may be implemented using XSLT or Razor, depending on what starter site you initially selected. Check below "Functions | XSLT Functions | ..." and if you do not find Layout.Navigation.Menu there then check below "Layout | /App_Data/Razor/...".

To copy a Razor Function simply copy the file, naming it like you want your new function to be named. XSLT Functions do not have a copy feature, here you need to create a new XSLT FUnction and copy over settings.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not familiar with XSLT or Razor so this simple task might be a bit of a challenge :)  Is there a way to write C1 functions directly in C#?